# Replace part of different class names with data attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, replace

**[FIDDLE EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cHtT6/13/)**

Is it possible to replace part of all the classnames in the table with  the strings in `data-term` in order?

This is the original markup:

```
<div class="query" data-term="Africa"></div>
<div class="query" data-term="Asia"></div>
<div class="query" data-term="Europe"></div>

<table><thead><tr>
  <td>Africa</td><td>Asia</td><td>Europe</td>
  </tr></thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr><td class="replacemefirst">Info</td><td class="replacemefirst">location</td><td class="replacemefirst">find</td></tr>    
   <tr><td class="replacemesecond">world</td><td class="replacemesecond">somewhere</td><td class="replacemesecond">belong</td></tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

What I want to achieve is to get the data attributes and replace the classes in table in order like this:

```
<table><thead><tr>
  <td>Africa</td><td>Asia</td><td>Europe</td>
  </tr></thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr><td class="Africafirst">Info</td><td class="Asiafirst">location</td><td class="Europefirst">find</td></tr>    
   <tr><td class="Africasecond">world</td><td class="Asiasecond">somewhere</td><td class="Europesecond">belong</td></tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

The following code isn't really working. I'm not sure how to find out each `replacemefirst` and `replacemesecond` and replace them with the data attributes. Any suggestions?

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $(".query").each(function() { 
     var div_terms  =  $(this).data('term'),
     replaceme = $('.replacemefirst').attr('class'),
     // not sure how to approach this part
      x = replaceme.replace("replaceme",div_terms);

      $('.replaceme??').addClass(x); 
      $('.replaceme??').attr('class',x);  
   });
});
```

Comment: eh? what are you trying to do here - I think you have over-thought a problem as I cannot see a reason for this - might just be me though!

Comment: I mean a reason for doing it this way - i think you want to .append() items to a table but as I said cant quite tell.

Comment: @GrahamRitchie, yes, it's very tricky. Due to some restrictions in my PHP script, I can't directly use `Africafirst`,`Africasecond` in the table. I have to dynamically change the placeholder classes first so that in my ajax script, it'll find the elements to append some data from a JSON file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All this looks really suspicious but you can try this http://jsfiddle.net/tarabyte/cHtT6/14/

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $(".query").each(function() { 
     var term  =  $(this).data('term'),
         replaceme = 'replaceme',
         first = replaceme + 'first',
         second = replaceme + 'second',
         target1 = $('.' + first).eq(0),
         target2 = $('.' + second).eq(0);

       target1.toggleClass([first, first.replace(replaceme, term)].join(' '));
       target2.toggleClass([second, second.replace(replaceme, term)].join(' '));

   });
});
```

Or more DRY version http://jsfiddle.net/tarabyte/cHtT6/16/

```
$(function() {
    var terms = $('.query').map(function(){
        return $(this).data('term');    
    }), selectors = ['first', 'second'];

    $.each(selectors, function(_, name) {
        var cls = 'replaceme' + name;
        $('.' + cls).toggleClass(function(idx){
            return [cls, terms[idx] + name].join(' ');
        })
    })    
});
```